# Instantiating Gameobject changes its shape

Tags: parent, instantiation, shapes

When instantiating an object from prefab by this way (in an empty project, Unity 2020.3.2f1):

```
myObject = Instantiate(preObject, Parent.transform);
```

This one changes myObject's shape very much. Actually, I don't know why.

Found a decision:

```
myObject = Instantiate(preObject);

myObject.transform.parent =Parent.transform
```

Is this a bug or Im just that lazy, I can't read documentation?

Comment: Just a guess. But has the parent object any other localScale than 1,1,1?? (Any of the parents for this matter)
If the parent is streched eg 1,1,2 it will also affect its children.

Comment: It was stretched 10, 10, 1. I'm not sure, if it was lossyScale or localScale. Going to do the same thing for cube 1,1,1 today

Comment: Golden Dremora, you are actually right. Parent was stretched by localScale, and that effected on children. lossyScale is read only, so the only way I know right now - is what written above

Answer (score 0):

I cant make a comment because I dont have enough rep ..

You could also set the transform as a parent and than just set the child scale to 1/parentScale.

```
obj = Instantiate(newObj, parent);
obj.localScale = new Vector3(1/parent.localScale.x, 1/parent.localScale.y, 1/parent.localScale.z);
```

If you have more than one parent with streched scale you can try the same with parent.losssyScale